# Can we use やばいぞ instead of やばいよ?

Tags: nuances, usage, particle-よ, particle-ぞ

Does "ぞ" make it more masculine-sounding or is it a different dialect?

Answer (score 2):

The both やばいぞ and やばいよ are not dialect, these expressions are used when one is getting involved in an unfavorable situation.

-ぞ is often used by male and sounds stronger. -よ sounds softer. For example, imagine a gang of thieves trying to steal something. Then one of the gang member noticed that some polices saw them and started to approach, so he warns his company.. In a situation like this, やばいぞ！ would be used better than やばいよ！

Answer (score 0):

To me, やばいぞ, which I have already heard, sounds like a reproach or a warning an older man would say to a younger person. やばいよ sounds more neutral but I would love a native Japanese speaker’s opinion.

I recommend you look for the topics about ぞ.